# CSS3 background randomly cutting my images

Tags: html, image, css

I have two html pages (index.html and about.html) with the same background in the body tag. I am using the following CSS to create the background:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

However, the browsers (Firefox and Chrome) are not positioning the image correctly. Since the background color is white, index.html has a white line under the background image. I am assuming that the image height is too short.

Yet, there is a block of white space under the background image of about.html, bleaching over a quarter of the page.

How does this happen when I'm using the same CSS.

While on this topic, what is the best way to manage a background image for different screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I can come up with was to use `background-attachment: fixed;`. This filled the entire background with my image.

I have not figured out as to why my CSS was displaying my background in different ways. This is something to look at.

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background-size:contain;
```

`contain` property scales the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.

Comment: I tried this before. This just shrunk my background image. In about.html, it is even smaller. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you first take a small slice of image by photoshop and save it for web and devices or take a small size by snipping tool.Than you will get a small image with small size.

than type bellow code

```css
 body {
   background-image: url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg');
   background-repeat: repeat;
 }
```

Comment: By default, the image is already repeating. That line seems redundant.

Comment: I know this line is redundant,but this line describe more specific.